# How to get the smallest in lexicographical order?

Tags: algorithm

I am doing a leetcode exercise

https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicate-letters/

The question is:

```
# Given a string which contains only lowercase letters, remove duplicate
# letters so that every letter appear once and only once. You must make
# sure your result is the smallest in lexicographical order among all possible results.
#
# Example:
# Given "bcabc"
# Return "abc"
#
# Given "cbacdcbc"
# Return "acdb"
```

I am not quite sure about `what is the smallest in lexicographical order` and why Given "cbacdcbc" then the answer would be "acdb"

Thanks for the answer in advance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select lexicographical smallest string after duplicates removed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34476853/select-lexicographical-smallest-string-after-duplicates-removed)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The smallest lexicographical order is an order relation where string *s* is smaller than *t*, given the first character of *s* (*s<sub>1</sub>*) is smaller than the first character of *t* (*t<sub>1</sub>*), or in case they are equivalent, the second character, etc.

So `aaabbb` is smaller than `aaac` because although the first three characters are equal, the fourth character `b` is smaller than the fourth character `c`.

For `cbacdcbc`, there are several options, since `b` and `c` are duplicates, you can decided which duplicates to remove. This results in:

```
cbacdcbc = adbc
cbacdcbc = adcb
cbacdcbc = badc
cbacdcbc = badc
...
```

since `adbc` < `adcb`, you cannot thus simply answer with the first answer that pops into your mind.

Comment: wait a second, isn't `adcb > adbc`?

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: @Geekuh. Your answer to the question is written in the last line :)

Answer (score 17):

You cannot reorder characters. You can only choose which occurrence to remove in case of duplicated characters.

```
bcabc
```

We can remove either first `b` or second `b`, we can remove either first `c` or second `c`. All together four outputs:

```
..abc
.cab.
b.a.c
bca..
```

Sort these four outputs lexicographically (alphabetically):

```
abc
bac
bca
cab
```

And take the first one:

```
abc
```

Answer (score 1):

clearly, the wanted output must contain only letter once.
now, from what i understand, you must pick the letters in a manner that will give you the best order when the leftmost letters come before in (abc? ascii?)
now you'd ask why "acdb" than and not "abcd". i think you don't take the first "cb" since you more c and b later, but you're have to take the "a" since there's only one coming now. then you must take c 'cause there are no more "d" after the next b. that's why you take c, and then d because no more d's later.

in short, you want to take it with best lexicographical order from low to high, but make sure you take all the letters while iterating over the input string.

Answer (score 1):

String comparison usually can be done in 2 ways:

- compare for first unmatched letter (called lexicographical ) for example `aacccccc` **is less** than `ab` because at second position `b` has been met (and `a` < `b`).
- compare string length first and shorter string is treated as less. If strings length are equal then apply lexicographical.

Second one may be faster if length of strings are known.

You question contains small error:

> why Given "bcabc" then the answer would be "acdb"

While origin was: "*Given "bcabc" Return "abc"*". That make sense that `abc` should be returned instead of `bca`

Answer (score 0):

`the smallest in lexicographical order` - your answer should be a subsequence of initial string, containing one instance of every char.
If there are many such subsequences possible (`bca, bac, cab, abc` for the first example), return the smallest one, comparing them as strings (consider string order in vocabulary).

`why Given "bcabc" then the answer would be "acdb"`
You confused two different examples

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some misunderstanding; the example states that for the input `bcabc`, the expected output should be `abc`, not `acdb`, which refers to the input `cbacdcbc`.