# Given a list of strings find a new string that is lexicographically smallest and is not a substring of any of the strings in the list

Tags: java, substring, lexicographic

I'm trying to solve this by diving into two parts.
First to get the lexicographically smallest values between a list of strings and then to check if it is not a substring in the given strings.

For the substring check part,

1. Create a Set from the given list of strings to remove duplicates
2. Set a boolean flag to true
3. Loop through the Set and use String contains to check if the new_string
4. If found, make flag as false and break
5. After the end of the loop check if the flag is true
6. If the flag is true, use this solution else go for the next value of new_string.

How do I find the list of lexicographically smallest values? I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34531748/how-to-get-the-smallest-in-lexicographical-order) to understand what lexicographically smallest means. In my case since there is a list of values should I first find the lexicographically smallest of each string and then try to find the new string which is smaller than these?

I don't need the code for it. I just want a pointer in the right direction and how should I approach this?

Note: I'm using Java

Comment: Easy with streams: `Optional<String> result = set.stream().filter(s -> set.stream().noneMatch(t -> !t.equals(s) && t.contains(s))).min();`.

Comment: I am not sure you have told us the entire question.  There is a very simple and very obvious answer to the question as asked: try "a", "aa", "aaa", ... in order until you find the first that is not a substring of any of the existing strings.

Comment: @rossum This is the entire problem as I was given. So you are saying to try with a, aa, aaa till the max length of the string in the list? If that doesn't work I'll go with each alphabet. How does it work if the solution is something like "ab"?

e.g. bcabc and cbacdcbc are given then the new lexicographically smallest string can be abcd.. right?

Comment: @AndyTurner could you please explain it a little bit :)